# Проведение документа 1с используя odata

Tags: javascript, 1с

Использую протокол Odata для создания документов в 1с на стороннем сервисе. Документ создается , все необходимые данные для успешного проведения  передаются в документ. Но все равно необходимо зайти в 1с нажать "записать и закрыть" для проведения.
Ниже код запроса на js который формирует и отправляет пост запрос.

```
data = await o('http://база/' + база + '/odata/standard.odata/Document_' +
              encodeURI('СЦ_ЗаказНаряд') + "(guid'" + instance.id + "')").post({
                //'Ref_Key': instance.id,
                'Date': moment(new Date(instance.created)).utcOffset(varFile.serverTime).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'),//serverTime
                'Неисправность': instance.description,
                'НомерИнцидентаКлиента': instance.clientIncidentNumber,
                'Исполнитель_Key': (executor && executor.foreignKey) ? executor.foreignKey : '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                'АдресКонтрагента': placeString,
                'НаименованиеОборудования': (device && device.product && device.product.name) ? device.product.name : undefined,
                'ОборудованиеКлиента_Key': (device && device.foreignKey) ? device.foreignKey : '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                'СерийныйНомер': (device && device.serialNumber) ? device.serialNumber : undefined,
                'Партнер_Key': (company && company.foreignKey) ? company.foreignKey : '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                'Posted': true,
                'ВидРемонта': 'Выездной',
                'КИКонтактногоЛица': contactString
              })
```

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь

Answer (score 0):

https://host/base/zone/odata/standard.odata/Document_РасходТоваров(guid'value')/Post?PostingModeOperational=false
Метод POST параметр указывает на неоперативное проведение.